# What counts as unintentionally performing an aveira?

Tags: sin

For example you accidentally light a fire on Shabbat, I assume this counts as unintentional. If you light a fire thinking it is a rabbinic prohibition, does this count as unintentional?

In a more general sense, if you perform an aveira believing the punishment to be less severe than it is, could this be called unintentional?

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8_%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95_%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%95%D7%9F
https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%A1%D7%A7
https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%92%D7%92

Comment: Chapter 7 of Masechet Shabbat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rambam in [Hilchot Shegagot 2:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Offerings_for_Unintentional_Transgressions.2.2?lang=bi) rules that even if one knew that something was a biblical prohibition, but was unaware that the punishment incurred is *karet*, it is classified as a *shegagah* and he brings a *chatat*.

I surmise that the same would be true in your case of an individual believing the prohibition is rabbinic; it would also be classified as a *shegagah* and he would bring a *chatat*.